django-dbbackup: server and pg_dump version mismatch
I faced on this error. who can help me?
command:
python manage.py dbbackup            

error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/passchain/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/passchain/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbbackup/utils.py", line 120, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 93, in handle
    self._save_new_backup(database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 106, in _save_new_backup
    outputfile = self.connector.create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 92, in create_dump
    return self._create_dump()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py", line 112, in _create_dump
    stdout, stderr = self.run_command(cmd, env=self.dump_env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbbackup/db/base.py", line 171, in run_command
    raise exceptions.CommandConnectorError(
dbbackup.db.exceptions.CommandConnectorError: Error running:  pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://root:%251fiY%263%40%21%4073%2A6%25ZJ6dT%40%40%253703%2A%5E%2A3%26%254oW046%264%25%250%24%40fexO%2AY%40CRhFy8%2A%240%5E05%2105%407%23@db:5432/db --format=custom 
pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_dump: detail: server version: 16.0; pg_dump version: 15.6 (Debian 15.6-0+deb12u1)


i have installed postgress-client and therre is not exist any pg_dump package newer version 15
my problem is i can not upgrade version of pg_dump to 16

have you tried updating postgres and psycopg2

my problem is that postgres version is too new for pd_dump.

Ya got it let me check and get back to you
